# Service Notification Is White

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications, foreground-service

I am developing a android app and I am testing it with 2 phones,one is huawei p20 pro and one is oneplus 6t.They are both running the same android version (Q-29).

when the notification shows in huawaei its working great,its colorful and its not white.
However when It shows on oneplus 6t its all white and ugly.

I read that its because the version of the phone but they are both running the same version and I can't figure it out.

I added this line in the manifest too:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/applogo" />
```

This is the notification code:

```
            RemoteViews notificationLayout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.customnotification);
            notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.customnotificationtext,getString(R.string.runninginbackground));


            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.title))
                    .setContentText(getString(R.string.runninginbackground))
                    .addAction(action)
                    .addAction(action2)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                    .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
                    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                    .setColorized(true)
                    .setColor(getColor(R.color.foreGroundBackgroundColor))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo)
                    .build();

            startForeground(2, notification);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Notifications should be in graysacale - if anything its huawei that's not following the specification if it's displaying colored icon.

Comment: @Pawel Thanks for replying,So is there any way I can detect if its going to be white and just change it with another icon?

Comment: I might be wrong but it seems Huawei is just displaying your apps icon ignoring whatever your provided to the notification the first place.